# Bash script to clone Git repo and run another bash script

Tags: bash, git, shell, sh

I'm having some issues with `PYTHONPATH` with a bash script I'm trying to run. There's 2 bash scripts, `clone_and_run.sh` is in a root folder. This is cloning a remote Git repo and then running another bash script in the root of that Git repo.

However, after cloning the repo and executing `run.sh`, that second script cannot run the Python scripts in the repo. But if I go into the repo root and execute `run.sh`, it works fine.

Here's the folder structure:

```
root
|----clone_and_run.sh
|----repo(after cloning from remote)
    |----source
         |----script.py
    |----run.sh
```

```
clone_and_run.sh:

#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

PYTHONPATH=`pwd`./repo/:$PYTHONPATH

git clone https://---------(redacted)

bash ./repo/run.sh
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/../repo:$PYTHONPATH

python ./source/script.py
```

This is the error I get when I execute `clone_and_run.sh`: `python: can't open file './source/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

After cloning, if I go into `repo` and execute `run.sh` directly, it works fine. I tried different `PYTHONPATH` on both scripts, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't cd in, the current working directory `.` when `run.sh` starts isn't the script's directory, it's wherever the invoker's running.

To find an invoked script's directory my usual method is `readlink -f $0`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue!